# How to iterate through URl in python3 using request module

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on fetching data from APIs which has ids in the URL and iterating through a set of ids from a file.i am passing headers and payload to the server

`www.example.com/<id>`

But request module is not allowing me to add id into the URL making the response 404. Can someone help in how to iterate multiple URL in for loop ?

I tried string concatenation and format style, but did not help.

```
with open('alerts_id') as ids:
    for id in ids:
        url = "www.example.com/{}".format(id)
        print(url)
        headers = {
                  'content-type': "application/json",
                  'prefer': "status 200",
                  'Authorization': "Basic xxxxxx"
                  }
        payload = ""
        response = requests.get(url ,data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
        print(response.text)
```

i expect the output from the API, but i get back not found. But when i manually pass the id. It works

Output:

www.example.com/24568

Not found

Comment: try printing variable `url` in the python itself and see what url is formed. If it's giving 404, it means that it's really not found. But if you are able to get response if you hit manually, it means there is some mismatch in url that is being formed by your script

Comment: i tried printing the URL and URL is formed, but i am suspecting when the URL is passed to request module it is not expecting that format.

Answer (score 0):

As per the url, that you have printed, your program seems working correctly. This URL `www.example.com/24568` is actually `404 Not Found`. The page that you are seeing after hitting this URL would be configured in server to show in case 404 is there.

**Verification 1**: curl command

```
C:\Users\kamal>curl -Iks www.example.com/24568
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2019 15:57:12 GMT
Expires: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 15:57:12 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 03 Jun 2019 06:56:08 GMT
Server: ECS (oxr/8313)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: 404-HIT
Content-Length: 1270
```

**Verification 2**: browser network tab (Right click >> Inspect Element >> Network)

[image]